# jbilling installation: tomcat unable to run

Tags: java, tomcat

I installed jbilling application in my system. download jbilling latest version in jbilling site. I follow installation procedure when I was run the jbilling startup batch file the tomcat unable to run. how to fix this problem?

In below is given a [procedure](http://dev.jbilling.com/documentation/users/installation/windows). I have a problem in last step..the tomcat window is not open.

> 1. Download and install Java. You will only need the Runtime Environment (JRE).
> 2. Download the most recent version of jBilling. 
>       Please Note: Ensure that you download the binary package, not the source. The source has the suffix '-src'. 
>       Example: Download jbilling-1_0_0.zip, not jbilling-1_0_0-src.zip.
> 3. Unzip the jBilling file (jbilling-3_0_0-RC2) you have downloaded. To unzip the file: 
>      3.1 Right click on the zipped file. A menu will appear. 
>      3.2 Select the menu option: Extract All. A new unzipped file with the same title (jbilling-3_0_0-RC2) will           appear in your Downloads folder.
> 4. Copy and paste the unzipped jBilling file from your Downloads folder, into your C:drive, Applications folder. 
>       Please Note: If you do not have an Applications folder in your C:drive, you will need to create one before moving onto step 5.
> 5. Open your computer’s Command Shell progam. 
>      5.1 Click on your start menu. 
>      5.2 In the search box, enter the text, cmd. The program will appear on the start menu. 
>      5.3 Click on the program to select it. The Command Shell program window will open.
> 6. Startup jBilling using the
>      Command Shell program. 
>      6.1 Type cd.. into the Command Shell program, and then press the Enter key. 
>      6.2 Repeat step 6.1. Press the Enter key. 
>      6.3 Type cd applications. Press the Enter key. 
>      6.4 Type cd jbilling-community-3.0-rc2. Press the Enter key. 
>      6.5 Type cd bin. Press the Enter key. 
>      6.6 Type startup.bat. Press the Enter key. A Tomcat window will appear on your screen. 
>      6.7 Wait for Tomcat to finish starting up. When it is complete, the text: INFO: Server startup in (a number)           ms, will appear in the Tomcat window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

server to find jvm in jre\bin\server\jvm. but jre does not have server.it's have client folder only..to create server folder to copy jvm.dll from client and paste it

Answer (score 0):

May be the Tomcat window does not require to pop-up, the command ran in the same window you executed it? You should check the logs actually, about what do they print. Does the window say tomcat started in so an so seconds?